# Aligning bounding box on probability confidence Map

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, cluster-analysis, tracking

I am trying to determine the high probability region in some data points. The probability is already computed and the approximate bounding box of the region is computed using Kalman Filter. However, the prediction by Kalman filter misaligns the bounding box in some offset.

As you will see in the image, the red boxes contains probability between [0,1) (Brighter region implies higher probability), while the grey region is probability of 0. These probabilities are computed and assigned in some prior functions which I have omitted in this question and I will go straight to the problem I am facing.

All i need is to align the blue bounding box on the region of high probability distribution (shown in Green line). I can do that using some trial and error such as shift left, right, up and down but for long iteration of my whole program, such method seems not to work well and sooner or later, gives incorrect estimates and the whole program drifts from the optimal solution.

Another method I read of its to use mean-shift but I am not sure how to apply it just in this part of the problem.

Nevertheless, please advise me on what are some possible algorithms or method I can use to correctly align the bounding box in the problem, as shown in Figure.[image: Initial estimates of the bounding box by kalman filter]

This picture shows the optimal solution i.e the green bounding box shows the correct region of interest.

[image: Green line shows the good match region]

Comment: performance critical or not? You could try Convolution: create a Mat with 1 values with size or your ROI and compute 2d convolution filter on your map. the filter answer with the highest response should be your optimum. To do that efficiently for a big map, you can use fourier transform (afaik openCV does this internally if it thinks it's more efficient).

Comment: @Micka yes, performance is critical in this case. Could you provide some highlights n 2D convolution filter please. Do you mean I do convolution filter on my probability confidence map as shown on the figure or on the original image?

Comment: yes, if I understand you right you know how big your blue bounding box is. If you use a filter of that size (filled with ones), you'll get the region with the biggest sum of probabilities afaik.

Comment: Oh ok I think I got that. So do you mean something like Sliding window of bandwidth same as ROI..

Comment: yes, similar. But with fourier transform it should be quite efficient I guess. Maybe I can try that for you tomorrow.

Comment: @Micka thanks for your comment and help. I will be trying as well and if u attempt it than please post the solution so I can compare. Thanks

Comment: @Micka i think i solved it using Convolution as you highlighted and Gradient Ascent Algorithm. The gradient ascent is used to find the maxima of the convolution and set the alignment on that maxima region.Thanks for your advice.